# mysql query: LIKE %$var% but not when $var empty

Tags: php, mysql

Using this query to bring up ringtones.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from ringtones where (artist LIKE '%$artist%' or title LIKE '%$title%') and id!='$ringtoneid' limit 50");
```

Question is:
How to prevent from displaying all rows when $artist or $title are empty?
Without query variables involved (checking and putting appropriate query string in PHP variable).

Other "thoughts" about it?

Thanks.

Comment: That query only displays the first 50 rows in any case

Comment: You **really** should be using prepared statements.  Read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com) if you don't know why.

Comment: Don't use double `%` it would really affect performance in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the additional condition:

```
   AND '$artist$title' != ''
```

Comment: where ((artist LIKE '%$artist%' and '$artist' != '') or (title LIKE '%$title%' and '$title' != '') ) and id!='$ringtoneid'

Answer (score 0):

Dont add the conditions to the WHERE clause unless $var is set:

```
if (isset($artist)) 
    $condition .= "artist LIKE '%$artist%'"
....
$result2 = mysql_query("select * from ringtones where $condition");
```

But again as Bobby Tables has mentioned, you need to use prepare statements

Comment: Aren't SQL injection attacks avoided with mysql_real_escape_string(); ?

Comment: Took that back :) It's generally a good idea to use prepare statements if you need to rerun a query more than once and it improves the data transsfer rate between your client and server. And yes you need to escape them

Comment: User with less rep is telling me.. =))